# iphone 4s did not work after trying to upgrade from ios 5 to ios 6 unsuccessfully

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

my iphone 4s was with ios 5.0 and already jailbreak when purchased,  I just tried to upgrade it to 6.13, on it own (which is I did not hook up my iphone with my computer nor iTunes at that time),

After a while, my iphone screen asks me to connect my iphone to iTunes, so I connect it to my computer, but then, the worst thing happened>>  ITunes says it detected my iphone is in recovery mode, and I must restore my iphone to its original setting before it can be used with iTunes.

It is a nightmare, I don't want to lose all my data, messages, pics.

Can anyone help?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to kick off your iPhone from recovery mode? This could be done with programs such as Tiny Umbrella or ReiBoot.

Comment: No, because I didn't know what to do. Now I will try Tiny Umbrella. Thanks.